# Process several thousand messages with a single Service Bus sender

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus

I am utilizing Azure Service Bus with a .NET Core 3.1 application. My application receives thousands of requests and places them in the topic. The question I want to ask is whether I should create a new sender for each message or if a single sender should process all messages.
My current implementation is:

```
private async Task EnqueueAsync(ServiceBusMessage message, string queueOrTopicName)
{
    var sender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(queueOrTopicName);
    try
    {
        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
        _logger.Info($"Message has been published to {queueOrTopicName}");
    }
    catch (ServiceBusException ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"Error while publishing data to the Service bus: {ex}");
        throw new QueueException("Unable to publish data.");
    }
    finally
    {
        await sender.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

ServiceBusClient is registered as a Singleton and the topic has 5 subscriptions so far.

Comment: You don't need to create a sender per message. However, you cannot process messages using a sender. You'll need a receiver.

Comment: Yes, I do have a receiver and there I don't have any issue. I am just worried about creating new sender for each message

Comment: So can a single sender process thousands of messages? Also if there are concurrent calls?

Comment: You inject the topic name. If it's always the same, then inject the sender into this method and create it outside. Then you can use whatever is appropriate but it is not the concern of this method.  But what's more worrying: do not use string interpolation in logging message templates.

Comment: May I ask the reason for not using string interpolation in logging messages?

Comment: It has several reasons, not all may apply to your code or intent. For one, you deprive yourself of the possibility to use structured logging. The other - which I think is more pressing here - it's slower and less memory efficient than the recommended way. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/high-performance-logging for more information.

Comment: ^^ also: you are looking to maximize throughput, so think about if you really need to log _every_ execution of the happy path. And even if you need or want to keep some sort of stats, you can look into more efficient ways to keep them. Maybe a performance counter or telemetry... but I would benchmark those to find the 'least intrusive'.

Answer (score 1):

Below is **`code`** with which i am able to send multiple messages by creating one sender instance:

```
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
public class RithwikTest
{
    private readonly ServiceBusClient rsc;
    private readonly ServiceBusSender rith_sender;
    private int rithcounter=0;
    public RithwikTest(ServiceBusClient serBusClient, string x)
    {
        rsc = serBusClient;
        rith_sender = rsc.CreateSender(x);
        rithcounter++;
    }
    public int GetSenderCount()
    {
        return rithcounter;
    }
    public async Task EnqueueAsync(ServiceBusMessage info)
    {
            await rith_sender.SendMessageAsync(info);
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello Rithwik Bojja, Message has sent to : {rith_sender.EntityPath}");  
    }
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string rithcon = "Endpoint=sb://pysdksb.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=1ienlgav4=";
        string queOrTop = "rithq";
        var sbc = new ServiceBusClient(rithcon);
        var test = new RithwikTest(sbc, queOrTop);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var info = new ServiceBusMessage($"Message is {i}");
            await test.EnqueueAsync(info);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Hello Rithwik, Total sender instances created and count: {test.GetSenderCount()}");
    }
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

You can integrate your code with your messages.

Comment: Thanks, I found similar kind of example on Azure Service Bus quick start page and I tried it in the beginning and it works well. My major concern is that if a single sender can handle concurrent calls. If it can, then I can either create a singleton wrapper for sender or register my sender class as singleton and create sender in the constructor as you did.

Comment: Try and check if it can handle concurrent calls or not, AFAIK, for single instance this is the only way which i can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following 2 docs, I can safely use a single sender to process all messages.

I've created a IServicebusSenderProvider and registered it as a singleton and in the constructor of the class, I've called `this._serviceBusClient.CreateSender(topicName);` and then used IServiceBusSenderProvider in MessageSender class.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/245
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2

Comment: Link- only answers are frowned upon. Links tend to die. To improve, show how you adapted your code and keep the links as reference to the info you used to come up with your solution.